# JMeter Response Times Over Time too many UseCases

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I've created a JMeter load test to test our API.
Currently we have four defined Use Cases that we want to test.
The Testplan is set up like this:
[image]

When I execute the tests, the report for the Response Times Over Time looks like this:
[image]

I would have expected to find only the four defined Use Cases... what are the other Use Cases shown in the graph and how can I group them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can put your "Use Cases" under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) and tick "Generate parent sampler" box

   [image]
2. Another option is filtering the samplers labels you want to see at the charts via [`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)